# Cannot apply SpecFlow to use BDD : The SearchContext of the locator object cannot be null

Tags: c#, selenium, null, appium, specflow

I've already applied Nunit with OneTimeSetup/TearDown and POM in my project. I can run my test just fine with UnitTest as below :

```
[TestFixture]
public class UnitTest2 : AFixture
{
    [Test]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        CurrentPage = GetInstance<LoginPage>();
        CurrentPage.As<LoginPage>().Login("myname");
        CurrentPage.As<LoginPage>().GoToAuthenPage();
        CurrentPage.As<AuthenPage>().VerifyAuthen();
        CurrentPage.As<AuthenPage>().ClickContinue();
        CurrentPage.As<AuthenPage>().VerifyLogin();
    }
}
```

But when I tried to use Specflow and the Feature file + Stepdefs, it does not work anymore

My Feature file :

```
@LoginFeature
Scenario: LoginFeature
Given User open App
When Login in with username as "myname"
Then User should be navigated to AuthenPage
```

My Stepdefs class :

```
[Binding]
[Scope(Feature = "LoginFeature")]
public sealed class LoginSteps : AFixture
{
    [Given(@"User open App")]
    public void GivenUserOpenApp()
    {
        CurrentPage = GetInstance<LoginPage>();
    }
    [When(@"Login in with username as ""(.*)""")]
    public void WhenLoginInWithUsernameAs(string p0)
    {
        CurrentPage.As<LoginPage>().Login("myname");
        CurrentPage.As<LoginPage>().GoToAuthenPage();
    }
    [Then(@"User should be navigated to AuthenPage")]
    public void ThenUserShouldBeNavigatedToAuthenPage()
    {
        CurrentPage.As<AuthenPage>().VerifyAuthen();
    }

}
```

It throws this error when I try to run :

Message: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException : Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ----> System.ArgumentException : The SearchContext of the locator object cannot be null
Parameter name: locator

I dont know why the code works on my UnitTest but not with the Feature File. Please share your solutions. Any ideas are welcome and big helps.
Thank you

Comment: Could you post the code of the AFixture class also.

Comment: I'm not sure if the way you use quotes will work with `[When(@"Login in with username as ""(.*)""")]` -- can you change to single quotes for `'(.*)'` instead?

Comment: @AndreasWillich it is just the class for setting up the Unity for DI, and some onetimesetup/teardown methods. I will update it when I get back to office

Comment: @Domestus Its an automatical generation from specflow, when you press F12, it says no function is binding to that step and copy the code so you can paste to your stepdefs.cs class